# Is there a way to assign a key to an event "bind" in jQuery so that a new handler would overwrite a previous one with the same key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in which I need to bind a handler to an event, and then, if eventually I need to bind another handler, I need to unbind the previous.

I know I can do this if I have the reference to the previous handler, in this case I would just `unbind` it, but in my scenario it's difficult. Additionally, I know I can unbind every handler as well, which I'm trying to avoid.

What I want is something like this:

```
$("#myInput").bind("click", myHandler, "key");

// here, as I'm passing the same key, this handler will overwrite the previous
$("#myInput").bind("click", myHandler2, "key");
```

But this doesn't seem to exist.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please, can you create a sample on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, event handlers do not get overwritten. You need to manually remove them.

However, you can [namespace your event names](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names), so that you can remove the old ones without knowing them explicitly (and not just detaching all click handlers):

```
$("#myInput").on("click.key", myHandler);

$("#myInput").off(".key").on("click.key", myHandler2);
```

---

Otherwise, you will need to overwrite the handler manually:

```
var handler = null;
$("#myInput").on("click", function() {
    if (typeof handler=='function') handler.apply(this, arguments);
});

handler = myHandler;

handler = myHandler2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all event handlers bound to an element using .data() method, it returns array object. So you can find the last click handler. The code could be something like that:

```
var lastHandler = null;
jQuery.each($("#myInput").data("events"), function(i, event){
   if(i == 'click'){
      lastHandler = event[event.length-1].handler;
   }
});
$("#myInput").unbind("click", lastHandler);
```